# Accessing ForeignKey field value inside template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have two models Fleet and Ship, Ships are ForeignKey fields of Fleets:

```
class Fleet(models.Model):
    fleet_ship_n_01 = models.ForeignKey(Ship, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='fleet_ship_n_01', blank=True)
    fleet_ship_n_02 = models.ForeignKey(Ship, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='fleet_ship_n_02', blank=True)
    fleet_ship_n_03 = models.ForeignKey(Ship, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='fleet_ship_n_03', blank=True)
```

Ships itself also have many fields like:

```
class Ship(models.Model):
    ship_class = models.CharField(default='NoClass', max_length=200, help_text="Ship class")
    ship_tech_level = models.CharField(default=5, max_length=100, choices=tech_level)
    ship_mass = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, help_text="Ship mass")
```

I have an update view in which i am adding ships to Fleet:

```
class UVFleetDetails(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'fading_thrust/fleet_details_form.html'
    model = Fleet
    form = FleetForm()
    total_ship_mass = 0
    fields = ('fleet_ship_n_01', 'fleet_ship_n_02', 'fleet_ship_n_03', 'fleet_ship_n_04', 'fleet_ship_n_05',
          'fleet_ship_n_06', 'fleet_ship_n_07', 'fleet_ship_n_08', 'fleet_ship_n_09', 'fleet_ship_n_10', )


    def form_valid(self, form):
        fleet = form.save()
        fleet_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        fleet.fleet_id = fleet_id
        fleet.save()
        return redirect('fleet_details', pk=fleet_id)
```

here is its form:

```
class FleetForm(ModelForm):
    fleet_ship_n_1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(Ship.objects.all(), required=False)
    fleet_ship_n_2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(Ship.objects.all(), required=False)
    fleet_ship_n_3 = forms.ModelChoiceField(Ship.objects.all(), required=False)
    fleet_ship_n_4 = forms.ModelChoiceField(Ship.objects.all(), required=False)
    fleet_ship_n_5 = forms.ModelChoiceField(Ship.objects.all(), required=False)
    fleet_ship_n_6 = forms.ModelChoiceField(Ship.objects.all(), required=False)
    fleet_ship_n_7 = forms.ModelChoiceField(Ship.objects.all(), required=False)
    fleet_ship_n_8 = forms.ModelChoiceField(Ship.objects.all(), required=False)
    fleet_ship_n_9 = forms.ModelChoiceField(Ship.objects.all(), required=False)
    fleet_ship_n_10 = forms.ModelChoiceField(Ship.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Fleet
        fields = ('fleet_ship_n_01', 'fleet_ship_n_02', 'fleet_ship_n_03', 'fleet_ship_n_04', 'fleet_ship_n_05',
              'fleet_ship_n_06', 'fleet_ship_n_07', 'fleet_ship_n_08', 'fleet_ship_n_09', 'fleet_ship_n_10',)
```

Now when adding ships to a Fleet i want to display also important details about those ships. Like ship_class, ship_tech_level, ship_mass etc. But i am having trouble accesing it in the template. 
Below is part of my template:

```
             {% for field in form %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                        <td>{{ field }}</td>
                        <td> ??? How to display ship mass ???</td>
                    </tr>
             {% endfor %}
```